# Iterating through csv file in python to change values if string matches items in nested list

Tags: python, csv, iteration

My apologies if this question is very basic as I'm new to coding and I've taken on this project mostly to learn.

I'm trying to write a program that will run through a csv file containing bank transactions, and add a payee and category based on based on identifiers within the description. I've written this, which actually does the trick:

```
import csv

f = open('transactions_file.csv')
inf = csv.reader(f)

with open('output_file.csv', 'w') as outf:
  writer = csv.writer(outf)
  for row in inf:
    if 'RENT' in row[5]:
      row[2] = 'Landlord'
      row[3] = 'Rent'
      writer.writerow(row)
    elif 'CARR' in row[5]:
      row[2] = 'Carrefour'
      row[3] = 'Groceries'
      writer.writerow(row)
    else:
      writer.writerow(row)

writer.writerows(inf)
```

One solution would be to just keep extending this program indefinitely with more elifs, but that seems a rather inelegant, so I'd like to turn those if loops into a single function.

I figured the way to start going about this would be to turn the categories and descriptions into another csv file, like so:

```
RENT, Landlord, Rent
CARR, Carrefour, Groceries
```

Then inserting this bit of code into the program to create a nested list:

```
cat_reader = csv.reader(open('categories_file.csv'))
cats = []

for row in cat_reader:
  cats.append(row)
```

Now I get stuck. The list should look something like this:

```
cats = [[X0, Y0, Z0],[X1, Y1, Z1], ... , [Xn, Yn, Zn]]
```

So I'd need something that will iterate through it, doing this:

```
if 'X' in row[5]:
  row[2] = 'Y'
  row[3] = 'Z'
```

But I haven't been able to figure out you do this. Again, I apologize if the answer is really obvious. But I haven't been able to find it in any other questions.

Comment: just try implementing `cats` or I will say start iterating throught it you shall find your way easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? It assumes that if cat list is not empty,it has a length of at least 3 elements.

```
for cat in cats:
    if cat and cat[0] in row[5]:
        row[2] = cat[1]
        row[3] = cat[2]
```

Comment: Yep, this was it. Can't believe I spent so long banging my head against the wall on something so simple. Out of curiosity, why if cat and cat[0] rather than just cat[0]?

Comment: @mbensass it's just a sanity check to see if cat contains any values. If cat  is empty, it will skip it. If you are sure that each cat contains the values you need, you can remove it.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

first when you load your categories you want to keep then in a dictionary:

```
cat_reader = csv.reader(open('categories_file.csv'))
cats = {}

for row in cat_reader:
  cats[row[0]] = (row[1], row[2])
```

after that your transaction processing code will look like this:

```
with open('output_file.csv', 'w') as outf:
  writer = csv.writer(outf)
  for row in inf:
      new_categories = cats.get(row[5])
      if new_categories is not None:
         row[2] = new_categories[0]
         row[3] = new_categories[1]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I learnt a lot going through this, but it won't work in the program because there are instances where the key doesn't exit in row[5] -- either because the string is, for example, "CARREFOUR" instead of "CARR", or because there just isn't a match. In those instances it returns N/A in row[2] and row[3] instead of leaving them unchanged.

Comment: Right.  I suppose my original code didn't behave the same way as your posted example.  I've updated my answer.  Though, you should've been able to figure it out on your own.

Comment: You're right, I should have been able to figure it out on my own. Your answer has been a massive help, and I appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score -2):

A simple double loop should do the trick:

```
with open('output_file.csv', 'w') as outf:
  writer = csv.writer(outf)
  for row in inf:
    for cat in cats:
      if cat[0] in row[5]:
         row[2] = cat[1]
         row[3] = cat[2]
         writer.writerow(row)
         break
      writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Thank you! This pretty much did the trick, although on the first take it duplicated most of the transactions. But that was sorted after removing out the writer.writerow(row) inside the if loop and shifting the indentation on the second writer.writerow(row) one to the left.

Comment: Yeah, sorry...I didn't quite understand how you wanted to write out the rows.  Glad you were able to get your program working!